# display input value from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to set the value of input from state however not successful.

Here is my attempt

```
state={
    value: ["one","two","three"]
}

render (
    return(
    {
        this.state.value.map(val=>{
          return <Input type="radio" value={val} />
        })
    })
)
```

the result I am getting is only one input element without the value displayed. as

```
*
```

What I am looking for is for three input element with there value displayed as

```
* One
* two
* Three
```

Comment: Is your component class a stateless functional component written using [es6 arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)? If so, you cannot declare a state for that component class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your **render** like follwong.

```
render() {
    return (
        this.state.value.map(function(val) {
            return <div> <input type = "radio" value = {val}/>{val}</div>
        })
    )
  }
```

[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-spun5r)

**Note:** If you want that you will be able to select only one radio button, in that case you need to group the radio button together by giving a common name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
state={
value: ["one","two","three"]
}

render(
 return(
   { this.state.value.map(val=> (
    <Input type="radio" value={val} />
   )
  )}
 )
)
```

Comment: Oh I think you have modified your question, is not?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have imported the Input component of it's a component.
Like
`import Input from './Input` or the exact path.
If you don't have a Input component, you need to change the Input to input a HTML element.

```
state={
value: ["one","two","three"]
}

render() {
   return (
<div>
{
   this.state.value.map(val => (<Input type="radio" value={val} />))
}
<div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "Input" is itself a component then check whether you have added "export default" and returning an input element from that component. Also, check whether you have imported it correctly from the component where you are calling it. 
If it is a controlled component then you must use value.
Check and let me know in the comments below.